# Sequencer alpha over problem

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm trying to compose two strips, an object with an alpha mesh and a background, when I do this in the compositor I get the right look:

[image]

But that's how it looks in the sequencer also using alpha over and with the same frames:

[image]

Changing the strip from straight to premultiplied didn't have any effect

What I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I made a test. I created this image with some black squares with little different alpha between them and I composed the image in the compositor and also in the sequencer. The sequencer doesn't seem to handle well these little alpha variations the first line looks the same, all black. While in the compositor you can see the little difference between the squares.

[image]

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LEPrFHsLEWRuwtNhrNC9NdmQgAE0KKG2/view?usp=sharing

Could this be a bug?

Comment: You create only a Viewer output node which doesn't affects anything outside the Compositor. You have to add a Composite or a File Output.

Comment: That is not the problem... I just wanted to show how the foreground composition with alpha over works when I use the compositor and doesn't work in the sequencer (those little gaps which are transparent in the compositor should also be transparent in the sequencer, but they are black)

Comment: Actually, those gaps are transparent in the sequencer but just a little bit, almost nothing, this way it's impossible to see the white background through them. And they are both the same image also using the same color management, I don't know why the alpha of this image works differently when I compose background and foreground in the sequencer.

Comment: Just edited the post with more details I found

Comment: If you crate a composition graph it won't affects the input picture, so this won't work this way. You have to solve this problem only in the Compositor. You can animate those nodes too to earn the fades and other effects. You have to add a file output node, render a png sequence, then create a video file from the rendered images in the VSE. Probably there is no other way in Blender.

Comment: I think it's "color space" related thing. Try "Linear" mode for VSE in Color Management settings.

Comment: Thank you Serge L! I didn't know this specific color management setting for the VSE, I tried changing the color space for each strip directly, but it didn't work. Your solution helped me!